# Ranges are sorted however I get "sort method of range Class failed" error

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

On sheet "all" I have ranges of data, column A to AC. The begining of each range is defined by a string containing "#" in column A.  The routine below inserts a blank row above each row with "#" and sorts each range based on values in column H in the desending order. At the end all inserted blank rows are deleted.

When I run the code the sorting works, however, I get en error message "sort method of range Class failed" at

```
.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Sort Key1:=Range("H4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

Please help to improve the following code so no errors are produced.

```
Sub SortRanges()

Dim LR As Long
Dim myCount As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


With Sheets("all")
LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & LR)
With Rng

For i = LR To 1 Step -1

If InStr(Rng(i).Value, "#") > 0 Then
    Rng(i).Offset(0, 0).EntireRow.Insert

End If
Next
End With

.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Sort Key1:=Range("H4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

Set Rng = .Range("A3").CurrentRegion

r = Rng(Rng.Count).Row
LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
myCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Range("A1:A" & LR))

For i = 1 To myCount

.Range("A" & r).Offset(2, 0).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Sort Key1:=.Range("H4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Set Rng = .Range("A" & r).Offset(2, 0).CurrentRegion

r = Rng(Rng.Count).Row

Next i

LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Range("A1:A" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

.Range("A2:AC" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of excel are you using, 2003, 2010?

Comment: I have Excel 2010. Thanks

Comment: Is the sheet "All" currently visible?

Comment: @MatthewD I do have a header row A. Could that be the problem?  If so, what should I do? Thanks

Comment: THe header should not matter.  I'm not sure about the Key1:=Range("H4") maybe try Key1:=Range("H:H")

Comment: changing "H4" to "H:H" didn't seem to help. Thanks

Comment: Try selecting the range before you sort it.  .Select

Comment: `.Range("A" & r).Offset(2, 0).CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Select` didn't seem to help

Comment: Does the first section sort and then you get an error on the second sort?  Maybe inserting the blank rows is causing the issue.

Comment: all sections sort fine but I get an error message before the blank rows are deleted.  We need the blank rows to define the ranges.

Comment: You need to qualify the key range too: `Key1:=.Range("H4")` and not just `Key1:=Range("H4")`

Comment: Nothing seems to work, I'm able to escape the error with `On Error Resume Next` but it's not really a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting the blank rows isn't necessary for the sorting, you just have to define your sorting range. The example below determines the range of each section and sorts it, down to the first empty cell.

**EDITED:** added logic to sort all sheets except those designated as skipped

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    '--- sort each section by column H
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim section As Range
    Dim sortCol As Range
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim skipSheets As String

    skipSheets = "Sheet1,After Sort,Unsorted"

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------------"
        Debug.Print "Checking sheet " & sh.Name & "... ";
        If InStr(1, skipSheets, sh.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "sorting!"
            Set section = sh.Range("A2:AC2")
            Do While True
                startRow = section.Row
                numRows = RowsInSection(startRow)
                Debug.Print vbTab & "section starting at row " & Format(startRow, "@@@") & _
                                    " with " & Format(numRows, "@@@") & " to sort: ";
                If numRows > 1 Then
                    '--- the section to sort does NOT include the first row
                    '    (with the "#" as the first character in column A)
                    '    so shift the section range down by one row and expand
                    '    to include all the rows
                    Set section = section.Offset(1, 0)
                    Set section = section.Resize(numRows - 1, section.Columns.Count)
                    '--- now set the column range on which to sort
                    Set sortCol = sh.Range("H" & startRow + 1, "H" & startRow + numRows - 1)
                    Debug.Print "range: " & section.Address;
                    Debug.Print " sort key: " & sortCol.Address
                    '--- finally sort it!
                    section.Sort Key1:=sortCol, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
                                 OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
                                 Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
                End If
                Set section = section.Offset(numRows - 1, 0)
                If IsEmpty(section.Cells(1, 1)) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            Debug.Print "skipped."
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub

Function RowsInSection(startRow As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    i = startRow + 1
    Do While True
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Or Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 1) = "#" Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    RowsInSection = i - startRow
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, it works very well given that I have a blank cell between each range in col H.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this code to all of the sheet in the Workbook with the exception of some sheets and having problems, even though all sheets have the same format it doesn’t always sort correctly. I'm using for each loop `For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets If (sh.name <> "Access") And (sh.name <> "Report_1") And (sh.name <> "Report_2") And (sh.name <> "IGVLinks") Then With sh Set section = sh.Range("A1:AC1") Do While True ... Loop` Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Based on the code snippet in your comment, you're using `With sh` and then using `Set section = sh.Range...`. If you have the `With sh` you can omit the `sh.`

Comment: I've have tried removing sh. And the result is the same as before: the first two sheets are sorted but not the last two. However, when I run the macro on each sheet one at a time it works great. Could you please update your answer and include how to correctly apply your code to multiple sheets in the same workbook and omitting specified sheets? I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: The above edits allow all sheets to be sorted, except for those noted in the skipped list.

Comment: Thanks Peter, One of the sheets is still not being sorted.

Comment: Interesting. What's the name of the sheet? The test workbook I created had ten worksheets in it, and I tested a couple different skipSheets lists. All the required sheets were sorted just fine. Also, is there anything different on that sheet (such as missing "#" in column A, or a different data set?

Comment: The formating on all of the sheets in the same. it doesn't sort Sheet ("Total") but sorts Sheets "Colon", "Lung" and "Melanoma" when I run the code.  However, if I select the sheet "Total" and run the code it sorts it.  I can't understand to why. If you would like I could send you a copy of the data.  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83802/discussion-between-petert-and-user3781528).